# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' - without code changes

Tags: reactjs, electron, node-modules

This problem has been discussed before, however none of the provided solutions could resolve my issue.

I was working on my react project when I suddenly got a compilation error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path'
```

The app was working fine before, I did some small updates to one of my components when the message appeared.

I wonder now what could be the reasons that all of a sudden I’m getting these two errors?

I tried deleting the node_modules folder as well as package-lock.json, cleaning the cache and then doing a fresh npm i. Also I rolled back to my latest working commit to see if I made some breaking changes.

However I’m still getting the error.

Anything else I can try here?

//Edit: It seems like adding this line to my dev-dependencies resolves my issue:

"@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11”

When searching for it there are quiet some issues from the past few weeks coming up. Quiet interesting, since I didn’t update anything so something in the background must have caused some changes.

Comment: Technically it's nothing to do with node_modules... Haven't you changed your node version recently?

Comment: Try `npm install @types/node -D`

Comment: I did not change my node version. “npm install @types/node -D” did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of error to solve the problem you may try this change in you package.json file:

```
"browser": {
  "fs": false,
  "path": false,
  "os": false
}
```

This might help you to solve the error.

Comment: Sadly this also didn’t help. I also didn’t need any other code to begin with, it just stopped working all of a sudden. Also I didn’t update or change any packages.